# read upload file in play framework

Tags: java, web, upload, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm using play framework 2.1.0, upload files to `play-app/upload` folder.

then I run `play 'start -Dhttp.port=80'` to start server.

but when I upload a file to `play-app/upload` folder, it can not be access immediately.

**if I stop the server and start again, then I can access the file.**

How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

ps, I route `/upload` as below:

```
GET     /upload/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/upload", file)
```

Could it be that static files are loaded once? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Preferably create upload folder outside the application's folder and add it's **full** path like `/home/navins/upload-folder/` in `application.conf`, then you'll be able to access it whole time, also you will be able to upload files there not only with app (ie, by FTP) without need of restarting.

Comment: but I can't directly access the file throughout like http://localhost/upload/xxx.doc

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to define a sort of `Remote assets` controller. Basically, once a file is uploaded, you put it in a folder that is outside your application's folder. Then, use a controller that will let you access it. Here is an example: http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/08/edge-caching-with-play2-heroku-cloudfront

Here, James Ward creates a controller to access assets that are stored on cloudfront, what you need to do is to write a similar controller and replace the "content url" with the absolute path to your "Uploaded files directory".

Answer (score 1):

finally what I've solve it by adding access method in controller:

```
public static Result view(String filename) {
    File file  = new File(Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath() + "/upload/" + filename);
    return ok(file);
}
```

then, change route conf, you can access the files by the method.

BTW, if you are using play framework below 2.0, you may user:

```
    renderBinary(file, ContentType);
```